# Using Selenium without using any browser

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, browser, automation

I have been trying to do web automation using Selenium. Is there any way to use a browser like Chrome or Firefox without actually installing them, like using some alternate options, or having portable versions of them. If I can use portable versions how do I tell Selenium to use it?

Comment: This comment is to get the attention of experienced developers to get an updated answer.
I'll delete it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the browsers like [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) you have to install the full-blown browser.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Is Chrome installation needed or only chromedriver when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330322/is-chrome-installation-needed-or-only-chromedriver-when-using-selenium/62449076#62449076)

---

As an alternative you can use the **headless** [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) browser as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=tslv1.0'])
  driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
  driver.get("https://account.booking.com/register?op_token=EgVvYXV0aCJ7ChQ2Wjcyb0hPZDM2Tm43emszcGlyaBIJYXV0aG9yaXplGhpodHRwczovL2FkbWluLmJvb2tpbmcuY29tLyo2eyJwYWdlIjoiL3JlZGlyZWN0LXRvLWpvaW5hcHAtbHA_bGFuZz1pdCZhaWQ9MTE4NzM2MCJ9QgRjb2RlKg4QAToAQgBY5dGK8gVgAQ")
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [PhantomJS can't load correctly web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265022/phantomjs-cant-load-correctly-web-page/60271002#60271002)

---

### References

A couple of relevent discussions:

- [Do headless web browser need selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946455/do-headless-web-browser-need-selenium-webdriver/50948600#50948600)
- [Difference of Headless browsers for automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083952/difference-of-headless-browsers-for-automation/53099311#53099311)

Comment: Isn't Phantom dead?

Comment: phantom is dead. good luck guys. i hope there's alternative to this problem

Comment: @undetected Selenium phantom is dead, can you provide some alternative? It doesn't have to selenium, any portable library would do actually.

Comment: @CyberAvater [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871704/7429447)/Requests either will be a good candidate. Even [Headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49582462/7429447)/[Headless Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768243/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

Install Selenium typing `pip install selenium`.

It comes with a portable version of Chrome browser, no need to manually install any browser for this.

Chrome will show this message to indicate that it is being 'remote controlled:

```
"Chrome is controlled by automated test software"
```

Comment: But still your machine has to have a chrome browser to open from selenium code!!

Comment: yeah its a different version of chrome , it doesn't need your usual chrome browser

Comment: it will automatically comes inside python libs

Comment: As others said, check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330322/is-chrome-installation-needed-or-only-chromedriver-when-using-selenium