# Can we achieve testing of web application loading and content rendering in headless browser in test automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, headless, headless-browser

we have a requirement to test our web application through test automation using Selenium Webdriver

1. Validate web application is loaded completely or not
2. validate content is rendered or displayed without issues
3. Headless mode

My doubt is can we certify that web application is loaded and content rendered without issues?

in headed mode ? yes , but headless mode it browser will invoke without head

Can someone help me to understand and is it right way to do test automation?

currently I have implemented in head mode and certifying to achieve as expected

now the requirement is headless on CI .

Expectation: Is it right approach headless mode to test content render and web application loading?

Comment: How would you validate it in non-headless mode? By manually viewing it? If it's a automated script, please provide the code for it.

Comment: Automated way using Webdriver

Comment: Well then please provide some code for that check in your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Headless Browser

A [***Headless Browser***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099311/7429447) is just like a regular web browser except that it doesn't have a a visible UI shell, so no tabs, URL bar, input fields, buttons, etc. It's just the website and nothing else as there’s no GUI to navigate. A [*Headless Browser*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50948600/7429447) can be controled through an automated script or manually through a command-line interface and you can still validate rendered contents  without any issues.

---

### tl; dr

[Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/)